# Python Merge duplicate rows based on ID and join with comma if column values are unique

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file called Project.csv
I am reading this file using pandas df = pd.read_csv('Project.csv',low_memory=False)
Inside this CSV file, there are rows with duplicate Project ID and Name but the other Column data are unique. I was looking for a way to find duplicate rows based on Project ID and merge records with ',' if they are unique.
Project.csv
[image: project.csv]

I am looking to store this record in a data frame and filter it to make it look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simply groupby will do the job

```
after_df = your_df.groupby(['Project Id'])[['Project Name','Project Types','Owner']].agg(set)
```

This will give you a similar result to what you want. If you want to take out the key symbool of the strings parameters so you have a nice looking string do this.

```
after_df.astype(str).replace(r'{|}|\'','',regex=True)
```

Comment: This didn't work. My output is missing the Project ID column. and putting all the data in {'HydroPower'} format in place of just HydroPower